# C# - write Excel file content efficiently

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to write the contents of an array to an excel file - from C1 to the length of the array.

About the topic of writing multiple cells at once I found 
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309500/c-sharp-excel-write-to-multiple-cells)
, but as you can see 
[in my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583879/c-sharp-efficient-way-to-iterate-over-excel-worksheet)
such a solution is really inefficient. I'd like something on the lines of

```
Excel.Range range = worksheet.Range["A1", "A" + myArray.Length];
range.Value2 = myArray;
```

If I do this, though, the app crashes. Not an exception, it just becomes a blank window. Do you have an idea what I should do to write the array content to the column efficiently?

TIA

Comment: please provide a complete example to reproduce your error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty inelegant and brute-force, but if you want lean on the Excel/Interop side, the best way to do this is to paste an array of objects directly into the `Value` property of a range.  This is an example of pasting a simple array into a column:

```
// just a sample array
int[] array = new int[11] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };

object[,] pasteMe = new object[array.Length, 1];
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    pasteMe[i, 0] = array[i];

worksheet.Range["A1", "A" + array.Length].Value2 = pasteMe;
```

I think what you were missing is that you need a 2d array since Excel ranges have both length and width.

Proof it works:

[image]

Comment: This is neither inelegant nor brute-force, it is the preferred way to write non-trivial amounts of data to Excel if you're using interop (or even VBA within excel).

Comment: Thanks...  I was actually referring to the mapping of the 1d array to the 2d array — I am not sure if there is a better solution for that.